# Persist logging outputs after tests are run

Tags: intellij-idea, integration-testing

When running integration tests in IntelliJ, logging output shows up in the console while the tests are running but when all the tests are run, they disappear. Only the startup and shutdown logging output persist in the IntelliJ console. Is there a way to persist the other logging outputs after the tests are done?

Answer (score 0):

This should be done in your TestNG or JUnit run configuration

Go to "Logs" tab, select "Save console output to file" and choose the file to which you're saving the output.